# replacing anchor text with image

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

I want to replace anchor text with image using CSS. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id ="first">
<a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>

<div id ="second">
<a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#first #second a{
background:url(../images/layout/tab.png);
float:right;
}
```

Here is JsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/chhantyal/GDF9K/

Why is it not working? What's the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector isn't doing what you expect it to. Your current selector matches this structure:

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have to be verbose:

```
#first a, #second a {
  background:url(../images/layout/tab.png);
  float:right;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GDF9K/2/**

But if since you asked for the *right* way, I suggest you use a class:

```
<div id="first">
  <a class="foo" href="#">Read More</a>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <a class="foo" href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

And your CSS becomes:

```
a.foo {
  background: url(../images/layout/tab.png);
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. But, I also want to replace 'Read More'with an image. Currently, above code is not replacing image.

Comment: You can't replace the element with an image, as the text will always be above the background. You're better off using `<img>` tags inside of the `<a>` tags instead of using a `background` property.

Comment: a.foo {color:transparent;...} alonside the above will hide the text if you can't get to the html e.g. a wordpress module

Answer (score 1):

Check Updated [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDF9K/1/)

```
#first,#second a{
    background:url(../images/layout/tab.png);
    float:right;
}
```

For reference Check [this](http://css-tricks.com/5690-multiple-class-id-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

use `text-indent:-5000px` in the css

the text shoots off the screen, but the background-image should remain

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/GDF9K/4/

just replace the background url with your image url and set appropriate width and height.

Here is a preview at next step.

http://jsfiddle.net/GDF9K/5/

Hope it helps!